# Safari cannot connect to local URL: http://127.0.0.1:5000

Tags: python, macos, flask, safari

I try to run this simple flask hello word code:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
    return "<p>Hello, World!</p>"
```

but safari doesn’t want to connect to the url given by Flask (http://127.0.0.1:5000).
I'm using MAC OS M1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add at the bottom:

```
if name == "__main__":
      app.run(debug=true)
```

Comment: I did that and then I started the program, I have:
```
Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
```

But safari doesn't open the URL http://127.0.0.1:5000/

Comment: You have to go to that URL manually shouldn't automatically open, but if that doesn't work maybe try another browser.

Comment: Sorry my **apache server** was not activated. I just activated it and it works. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```py
   from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify

   app = Flask(__chataa__)

   # Store messages in memory for simplicity (not recommended for production)
   messages = []

   @app.route('/')
   def index():
       return render_template('index.html', messages=messages)

   @app.route('/send_message', methods=['POST'])
   def send_message():
       username = request.form.get('username')
       message = request.form.get('message')
       if username and message:
           messages.append({'username': username, 'message': message})
       return jsonify({'status': 'OK'})

   if __name__ == '__main__':
       app.run(debug=True)
```

3. Create an HTML template (index.html) to display the chat interface:

   ```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">
   <head>
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <title>Chat App</title>
   </head>
   <body>
       <h1>Chat App</h1>
       <div id="chat">
           {% for message in messages %}
               <p><strong>{{ message.username }}:</strong> {{ message.message }}</p>
           {% endfor %}
       </div>
       <form id="message-form">
           <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Username">
           <input type="text" id="message" placeholder="Message">
           <button type="submit">Send</button>
       </form>
       <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
       <script>
           $(document).ready(function() {
               $('#message-form').submit(function(event) {
                   event.preventDefault();
                   var username = $('#username').val();
                   var message = $('#message').val();
                   $.post('/send_message', { username: username, message: message }, function(data) {
                       $('#message').val('');
                   });
               });
           });
       </script>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).